# IntelliJ execute gradle test from root project

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, gradle

I've a gradle multiproject importend in my IntelliJ, and I want execute some test classes.

The structure is like:

```
root
|-module-a
|-module-b
```

**module-a** depends on **module-b**, so in the *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    compile project('module-b');
}
```

When I use gradle from the shell everything it's ok, I have to go in the **root** project dir and write:

```
./gradlew :module-a:test
```

And everything it's been tested.

When I click "*Run 'Tests' in 'module-a'*" from IntelliJ I have this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'module-a'.
> Project with path ':module-b' could not be found in root project ':module-a'.
```

So it seems, that IntelliJ is executing the gradle command from **module-a** and not from the **root** (this should be the correct behavior from what gradle wants).

How can execute this test inside IntelliJ? What I have to configure?

Comment: Could you say, where is settings.gradle file located? It use to be in the same folder as module-a and module-b folders to make it possible to run tasks not from the project folder. So, you might try to move it to the root folder from the module-a folder/

Comment: I have one settings.gradle in each folder: module-a, module-b and root

Comment: usually, a settings.gradle exists only the root folder, and not in the subprojects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a multi-project structure that looks like this

```
root
|-module-a
|-module-b
```

There is only one `settings.gradle` in the root folder, with the content:

```
include 'module-a', 'module-b'
```

The subproject folders do not contain a settings.gradle file. Then you refer to sibling projects as:

```
project(':module-b')
```

so your dependency would be declared as:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':module-b');
}
```

Please [see here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) for more information about multi-project structure.

Comment: I know this is old, but if anyone is looking for something like this as I was, I found this answer indirectly very helpful.  It made me consider what was wrong with my intellij setup.  I tried changing the run configuration so that it pointed to my root project's "build.gradle" rather than my subproject, then changed "run" as the task to "subproject:run".  That was it for me, I have been trying to figure out why my gradle run worked ok but couldn't run it from intellij.  Thanks.